# ld: fatal: file /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: php, makefile, solaris, configure

I'm trying to build PHP 7.4 on Solaris sparc 10, but I'm getting this error:

> d_objects.lo Zend/zend_object_handlers.lo Zend/zend_objects_API.lo Zend/zend_default_classes.lo Zend/zend_inheritance.lo Zend/zend_smart_str.lo Zend/zend_cpuinfo.lo Zend/zend_execute.lo sapi/apache2handler/mod_php7.lo sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.lo sapi/apache2handler/apache_config.lo sapi/apache2handler/php_functions.lo main/internal_functions.lo -lresolv -lrt -liconv -lintl -lrt -lm -lnsl -lsocket -lgcc  -o libphp7.la
> ld: fatal: file /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
> ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to .libs/libphp7.so
> *** Error code 1
> make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `libphp7.la'

My configure is as follows:

> ./configure --disable-xmlwriter --disable-xmlreader --disable-simplexml --disable-xml --disable-dom --with-apxs2=/usr/apache2/bin/apxs --with-gd --with-zlib --disable-ipv6 --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local --with-png-dir=/usr/local --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local --without-pear --with-openssl --with-mysqli --enable-bcmath --enable-ctype --enable-mbstring --with-gettext --prefix=/usr/php --without-libxml OPENSSL_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/openssl OPENSSL_LIBS=-L/usr/local/ssl/include SQLITE_CFLAGS=-I/usr/php/include/php/ext SQLITE_LIBS=-L/usr/php/include/php/ext ZLIB_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include ZLIB_LIBS=-L/usr/include ONIG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/php/ext/mbstring ONIG_LIBS=-L/local/include/php/ext/mbstring 
> --with-external-pcre 
> --with-pcre-jit 
> PCRE2_LIBS=-L/app/INSTALL_FILES/php-7.4.13/ext/pcre/pcre2lib 
> PCRE2_CFLAGS=-I/app/INSTALL_FILES/php-7.4.13/ext/pcre/pcre2lib 
> SQLITE_LIBS=-L/app/INSTALL_FILES/php-7.2.5/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite 
> SQLITE_CFLAGS=-I/app/INSTALL_FILES/php-7.2.5/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite

Environment is set as follows:

```
$ env|grep LD
```

> LDFLAGS=-L/opt/csw/lib/gcc -L/usr/local/lib -R/opt/csw/lib/gcc
>
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64=/opt/csw/lib/sparcv9:/usr/local/64/lib:/usr/sfw/lib/sparcv9
>
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/csw/bin/sparcv9:/opt/csw/lib/sparcv9:/usr/local/include/php/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite:/opt/csw/lib:/usr/local/64/lib:/usr/sfw/lib/sparcv9:/usr/apache2.2/pcre/lib:/usr/apache2.2/apr_util/lib:/usr/apache2.2/apr/lib
>
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32=/usr/local/include/php/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite:/opt/csw/lib:/usr/apache2.2/pcre/lib:/usr/apache2.2/apr_util/lib:/usr/apache2.2/apr/lib

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you building a 32 or 64 bit version?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You are building a 64-bit executable with the following environment variable set:

```
LD LDFLAGS=-L/opt/csw/lib/gcc -L/usr/local/lib -R/opt/csw/lib/gcc
```

Given this error:

```
ld: fatal: file /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

The shared object `/usr/local/lib/libiconv.so` is a 32-bit shared object.

You can either remove directories that have 32-bit binaries in them from your `LD_*` environment variables when building or running 64-bit binaries, or make sure the contents of any of those directories are all 32- or 64-bit if there's a 64-bit library in `/usr/local/lib` that you need.

You need to read the [**ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES** section of the Solaris 10 `ld.so.1` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5165/ld.so.1-1.html):

> **Environment Variables**
>
> Each environment variable can be specified with a `_32` or `_64`
> suffix. This makes the environment variable specific, respectively, to
> 32–bit or 64–bit processes. This environment variable overrides any
> non-suffixed version of the environment variable that might be in
> effect. Environment variables specified without a value, that have a
> _32 or _64 suffix, effectively cancel any associated generic environment variable setting.

You're mixing a lot of `LD_*` environment variables with and without the `_32` and `_64` suffixes, and you need to clean that up and be consistent so you don't wind up mixing 32- and 64-bit executable files.

And this looks downright wrong:

```
ZLIB_LIBS=-L/usr/include
```

Libraries in `/usr/include`???

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for the replies, that gives me something to work on !